# C++ Visual Studio error: Identifier cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lambda, path, filesystems

I'm trying to extract the value of dir_entry.path() in this code and want to copy it into compFileName.
The problem is that I keep receiving the error 'compFileName cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified.

I know it has to do with something related to lambda functions but I have zero experience in them.
Any advice on how I should solve this issue to achieve what I want?

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void search(const fs::path& directory, const fs::path& file_name, string &compFileName)
{
    auto d = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(directory);

    auto found = std::find_if(d, end(d), [&file_name](const auto & dir_entry)
    {
        string t = dir_entry.path().filename().string();
        compFileName = t;
        return t == file_name;
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use surrounding variables in a lambda unless you capture them.

You use `compFileName` which is defined in the surrounding scope, but it's not listed as a capture.

Simple fix: Add `&compFileName` to your capture list:

```
[&file_name, &compFileName](const auto & dir_entry) { ... }
```

Even simpler: Capture *all* used variables:

```
[&](const auto & dir_entry) { ... }
```